# filter items from a many to many relation table

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have a table 'many-to-many' `many_relation` with :

- `relation_id` unique id
- `set_id` link to another table with sets
- `element_id` link to another table with elements

So the idea is to have many sets representing 'groups' of elements (1 to many elements)

What I would like to do is to be able to select all the sets (`set_id`) that include given elements.
So for example, if elements are [1,2,3] and sets are [a,b]
imagine:

- set 'a' is 'linked' to elements 1 and 2
- set 'b' is 'linked' to elements 1 and 3
  then the table `many_relation` will be:

| relation_id | set_id | element_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | a | 1 |
| 222222 | a | 2 |
| 333333 | b | 1 |
| 444444 | b | 3 |

I would like to be able to:

- select sets linked to element 1 => [a,b]
- select sets linked to elements 1 and 2 => [a]

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT mr.set_id
FROM many_relation mr
  INNER JOIN element el ON mr.element_id = el.id
WHERE el.id in ('1', '2')
group by mr.set_id
having count(*) = 2
```

But I'm not sure this is the way to do, I don't like the count part..
Any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Will there always be only two element ?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur no, can be hundreds of elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select set_id
from many_relation
where element_id in (1, 2)
group by set_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- the "2" is the number of items in the `in` list
```

EDIT:

In Postgres, you can do this using arrays.  For instance:

```
select set_id
from many_relation
where element_id = any (array[1, 2])
group by set_id
having count(*) = cardinality(array[1, 2]);
```

This repeat the array for clarity.  You can define it using a CTE (for instance).  However, I suspect you are passing it in as a parameter, so `?` would just be in both places.

Comment: I know that but I would like to not have to count the number of items. So get rid of this condition. Especially because it is error prone. If there is a mistake and a set is linked two times to the same element, then it will be selected

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_agg() to match the conditions, without counting them:

```
WITH many_relation(relation_id, set_id, element_id) AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (VALUES
                (11111, 'a', 1)
            ,   (222222,'a', 2)
            ,   (333333,'b', 1)
            ,   (444444,'b', 3)) s
)
SELECT  set_id
FROM    many_relation
WHERE   element_id = ANY (array[1,2])
GROUP BY
    set_id
HAVING  array_agg(DISTINCT element_id) @> array[1,2];
```